# How do I Filter on a custom Level in log4net?

Tags: .net, configuration, logging, log4net

I copied the log4net samples to implement a custom log level, AUDIT. I defined AUDIT to have a value of 35000, between DEBUG 30000 and INFO 40000.

The following is my configuration section. I have one appender that logs all levels and one that is supposed to log only AUDIT levels (this is just for testing)

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" >
    <file value="testrun.log" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" >
      <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss:fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger{1} - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="FileAppender.Audit" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" >
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
      <levelToMatch value="AUDIT" />
    </filter>
    <file value="testrun.audit.log" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" >
      <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss:fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger{1} - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>  
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender.Audit" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

The test method is

```
private static readonly IAuditLog log = AuditLogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
public static void Main()
{
    log.Debug("Debug");
    log.Audit("Audit");
    log.Info("Info");
}
```

However, the output of the appenders is the same...

```
13:09:11:540 [9] DEBUG Program - Debug
13:09:11:560 [9] AUDIT Program - Audit
13:09:11:560 [9] INFO  Program - Info
```

The log4net debug output when parsing the LevelMatchFilter is

```
log4net: Loading Appender [FileAppender.Audit] type: [log4net.Appender.FileAppender]
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Unknown Level Specified [AUDIT]
log4net:WARN Unable to set property [levelToMatch] on object [log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter] using value [AUDIT] (with acceptable conversion types)
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddFilter] to object [log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter]
```

Comment: Update: I cannot filter on ANY level, even levels already built into log4net (like DEBUG).

Comment: This question helped me configure a log4net filter, but I must point out that logging and auditing - while often conflated - are two very different concerns in a serious system.  Mixing or equating the two is is not advised.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

log4net version 1.2.10 requires that you end a `LevelMatchFilter` chain with a `DenyAllFilter` if you want the behavior I described in the question.

```
<appender name="FileAppender.Audit" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" >
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
    <levelToMatch value="AUDIT" />
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
  <file value="testrun.audit.log" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" >
    <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss:fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger{1} - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 7):

You will need to add

```
<level>
  <name value="AUDIT" />
  <value value="35000" />
</level>
```

in your log4net config section.